# How to create a table with large amount of data that supports fast queries in a warehouse?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dynamic-sql

I have a large amount of data around 5M that are stored in a very flat table which has 12 Columns. This table contains aggregated data and it does not have any relationship with other tables. I want to run dynamic queries on this data for reporting purpose. The table contains Fields like `District`, `City`, `Year`, `Category`, `SubCategory`, `SaleAmount` etc

1. I want to view reports such as Sales between year 2010 and 2013.
2. Sales of each product in various year and compare them.
3. Sales by specific salesmen in a year.
4. Sales by category, Subcategory etc.

I am using SQL Server 2008, but I am not a DBA hence I do not know things like what type of indexes should I create? Which Columns should I index in order to make my queries work.

If the amount of data was small I would not have bothered about all these questions and just proceeded but knowing which columns to index and what type of indexes to create is vital in this case.

Kindly let me know the best way to ensure fast execution of queries.

**Will it work if I create a clustered index  on all my columns? or will it hurt me.**

Keep in mind that this table will not be updated very frequently maybe on monthly basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your very clear and specific requirements, I would suggest you create a non-clustered index for each field and leave it to the optimiser as a first step. (ie you create 12 indexes) Place only a single field in each index. Dont index ( or at least use caution ) any long text type fields. Also dont index a field such as M/F that has only 2 values and a 50/50 split. I am assuming you have predicates on each field, but dont bother indexing any fields that are never used for selection purposes.

If you still have problems after this, find the query analyser in sql server and use it to guide how queries are processed.

Multi segmented indexes are sometimes better, but if your queries are mostly restricting to a small subset of the table then single field indexs will be fine.

You might have residual performance issues with queries that use "order by", but lets just leave that as a heads up at this stage.

My reasoning is based on

1. You only have 12 columns, so we wont overload anything
2. There are only 5M rows. This is quite easy for sql/server to handle
3. The growth in the data is small, so index updates shouldnt be too much of an issue.
4. The optimiser will love these queries combined with indexes.
5. We dont't have typical query examples to specify multi segment indexes, and the question seems to imply highly variable queries.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Can you please explain if it will be useful to use Clustered index in this scenerio or will it make things worse. I was thinking that I could create a clustered index with most common fields like year, categories etc in the left and less relevant fields in the right but I have no experience of telling if it will work better than 12 separate indexes? Have you ever compared the two scenarios?

Comment: In sql/server a clustered index is used more to control physical placement of rows in the table http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx in databases you typically want an I/O to fetch as many relevant rows as possible, so cluster them together. In your case I would pick you want rows from same dates close to each other, so might cluster on year/month/day sort of thing, HOWEVER, when you load new records without clustering you should naturally get this anyway. Very big area itself...

Comment: The other thing you might be thinking is multi segment indexes, where one indx contains multiple fields, these can perform better for queries, better fit to predicates, I/O density, Pre sorted results, quasi vertical partitioning, etc, BUT, we would need to see common query examples as you must typically query the leading fields. An index on A,B with a query B=6 will often not use the index (some engines do in some cases, some dont). This is why I suggested single field indexes as start point.